# Commutation relation between su(N) and clifford algebra generators.

Tags: lie-groups, symmetry, clifford-algebras

Why does the $ \gamma_5 $ matrix commute with the generators of the $su(N)$ algebra?

In the case of the *chiral* symmetry from physics, [$Q_a$, $Q_b^5$] = $i \epsilon_{abc}Q^5_c$ where the $Q_a, Q^5_a$ form the $su(N)$ algebra.

In order for this to hold it must be so that $[T_a, \gamma_5]=0 $ , at least to my understanding.

I am aware of the fact that the gamma matrices under a unitary transformation create a new set of, say, $\tilde{\gamma}$ which transform like the first set. I am not sure, however, how that is applicable in this case.

The physical interpretation I have encountered in textbooks is *"they correspond to different algebras"*, however I am not satisfied by this, I need a stronger argument.

Comment: I considered posting this in physics.stackexchange, however I want to avoid receiving replies along the lines of " physical interepretation". I want a rigorous mathematical proof. Especially since the case at hand is not a particular su(n) but the general su(n) algebra.

Comment: I think this perhaps needs more physical intuition ? Is your definition of $Q_a^5 \equiv \int d^3x \psi_r^\dagger (x)(T_a \gamma^5)_{rs} \psi_s(x)$ and similarly $Q_a^5$ is the same without $\gamma^5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A bit of Theoretical Physics in QCD

I think this is best answered from a physics perspective. Let $\mathcal{L}_{QCD}$ be a QCD Lagrangian that is invariant under the gauge transformation,

$$\psi(x) \to e^{-i\alpha}\psi(x)$$

If all masses are equal in $\mathcal{L}_{QCD}$ then there is also an invariance,

$$
\psi(x) \to e^{-i\alpha^aT_a}\psi(x)
$$
where $\psi$ becomes a column vector with quark flavour indices and $T_a$ is the $SU(N_f)$ generator. If all quark masses vanish then we also obtain a chiral symmetry,

$$
\psi(x) \to e^{-i\alpha^a\gamma^5T_a}\psi(x)
$$

The chiral projection as you will know is defined as $\psi_{{R},{L}}(x) = \frac{1}{2}(1 \pm \gamma^5)\psi(x)$ from this we can construct $\gamma^5\psi = \psi_R - \psi_L$

### The Maths

To obtain the algebra, look at the infinitesimal form,

$$
e^{-i\alpha^a\gamma^5T_a} = 1 - i\alpha^a\gamma^5T_a + \cdots
$$

where $\alpha$ are angles and $T_a,\gamma^5$ are matrices.

We can decompose the field into a linear combination $\psi=\psi_L+\psi_R$ and express a new Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}_{QCD} =\mathcal{L}_{QCD,R} + \mathcal{L}_{QCD,L}$ which are each invariant under separate transformations,

$$
\psi(x)_{L,R} \to e^{-i \alpha^a_{L,R} (T_{L,R})_a}\psi(x)_{L,R}
$$
These separate invariances must be preserved in $su(n_f)\times su(n_f)$ so we must have that,

$$
\psi(x) \to \psi(x)_R - i\alpha^a_R(T_R)_a \psi(x)_R + \psi_L - i\alpha^a_L(T_L)_a \psi_L + \cdots 
$$
and so we can compare terms,

$$
- i\alpha^a_R(T_R)_a \psi(x)_R - i\alpha^a_L(T_L)_a \psi_L 
=
- i\alpha^a\gamma^5T_a\psi(x)
$$
to see that we can project out left and right handedness of the generator and also that $\alpha^a(T_{R,L})_a\psi(x)_{R,L} = 0$

We can deduce that $[\gamma^5,T_a]\psi(x)=0$ since we can either project out the chirality of $T_a$ or $\psi(x)$ but whichever we choose, due to orthogonality, the result will be the same.

### Very Hand-Wavy Summary

We can also deduce that chiral symmetry would not be conserved if the right-handed and left-handed $T_a$ gave non-zero contributions from both $\psi_R,\psi_L$ and since the whole point is to project $\psi_R$ and $\psi_L$ you can deduce that any way you look at it, even if we assume $[T_a,\gamma^5]\ne0$ alone, then the resultant action we demand once acting on $\psi$ renders it the same as $[T_a,\gamma^5]=0$

### References

- [*Dirac, Majorana and Weyl fermions*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.1718.pdf)
- [*Conceptual Foundations of Modern Particle Physics*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=iYBZ1QRt9j4C&pg=PA172&dq=chiral%20algebra%20su(n)%20x%20su(n)&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu4-n_q5DMAhUBAxoKHQ8DCd4Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=chiral%20algebra%20su(n)%20x%20su(n)&f=false)
- [*Random Standard Model Lectures*](http://www.ecm.ub.es/~espriu/teaching/doctorat/standard_model/SM_lect4.pdf)